# Alaways goin in onFailure in retrofit2.0

Tags: retrofit2

I am trying to hit the api : www.xyz.com/abc_cc/cc/userregister/newuser

This is my Code :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static final String BASE_URL = "abc.com/abc_cc/cc/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
.client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Endpoints endpoints= retrofit.create(Endpoints.class);
        endpoints.newuser("{\"full_name\":\"sss\",\"states_id\":\"20\",\"mobile\":\"9876543210\",\"password\":\"******\",\"accept_terms\":true,\"Userid\":\"0\",\"refer\":\"\",\"ip-address\":\"1.2.3.4\",\"device_type\":\"samsung J5\",\"os-version\":\"5.0.1\",\"client\":\"app\",\"secret_key\":\"44\"}")
                .enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<Items>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<Items> call, retrofit2.Response<Items> response) {
                        System.out.println("onResponse : "+response.message());
                        System.out.println("onResponse : "+response.body());
                        System.out.println("onResponse : "+response.code());
                        System.out.println("onResponse : "+response.errorBody());
                        System.out.println("onResponse : "+response.isSuccessful());
                        System.out.println("onResponse : "+response.raw());
                        System.out.println("onResponse : "+response);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<Items> call, Throwable t) {
                        System.out.println("onFailure"+call);

                    }
                });


    }

    public static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {

        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
                }
            } };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts,
                    new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext
                    .getSocketFactory();

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            okHttpClient = okHttpClient.newBuilder()
                    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                    .hostnameVerifier(org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER).build();

            return okHttpClient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Interface :

```
public interface Endpoints {
    @POST("/userregister/newuser")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Items> newuser(@Field("Data") String Data);

}
```

POJO class :

```
public class Items {
    @SerializedName("Response-Status")
    @Expose
    private Boolean responseStatus;
    @SerializedName("Response-Validate")
    @Expose
    private Boolean responseValidate;
    @SerializedName("Response-Message")
    @Expose
    private String responseMessage;
    @SerializedName("Response-Data")
    @Expose
    private ResponseData responseData;

    public Boolean getResponseStatus() {
        return responseStatus;
    }

    public void setResponseStatus(Boolean responseStatus) {
        this.responseStatus = responseStatus;
    }

    public Boolean getResponseValidate() {
        return responseValidate;
    }

    public void setResponseValidate(Boolean responseValidate) {
        this.responseValidate = responseValidate;
    }

    public String getResponseMessage() {
        return responseMessage;
    }

    public void setResponseMessage(String responseMessage) {
        this.responseMessage = responseMessage;
    }

    public ResponseData getResponseData() {
        return responseData;
    }

    public void setResponseData(ResponseData responseData) {
        this.responseData = responseData;
    }

}
```

I am getting this response :

```
{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=www.xyz.com/userregister/newuser}
```

I have given the proper url then why is it taking only half of it?

I have tried the example from https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845. This example and the link given in the example are working fine, but if I do the same with my url then I get the above error

Comment: refer to accepted answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352159/retrofit-2-removes-characters-after-hostname-from-base-url

Comment: @hsl if i do that then it goes to onFailure

Comment: sorry, i didn't read carefully enough. remove the leading "/" from your Endpoint.newuser() definition.

Comment: @hsl I am sorry i did not understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Hope kindly check your parsing issues may occurred.

```
 @Override
public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<Items> call, Throwable t) {
 System.out.println("onFailure"+call);
```

//add this lije you got exceptions.

```
 t.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Endpoints` interface for this:

```
public interface Endpoints {
    @POST("userregister/newuser")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Items> newuser(@Field("Data") String Data);

}
```

Note that I removed the trailing slash `/`. This way Retrofit appends the path you defined to the BASE_URL.

Comment: tried this, always going in onFailure. And i tried the same url via different httpurlconnection method, that is working fine. And also in postman

Answer (score 0):

refer to the [docs for Retrofit.Builder](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.Builder.html#baseUrl-okhttp3.HttpUrl-) for a more detailed explanation, but pay particular attention to these bits:

> Base URLs should always end in /.
>
> A trailing / ensures that endpoints values which are relative paths
>   will correctly append themselves to a base which has path components.
>
> ...
>
> Endpoint values which contain a leading / are absolute.
>
> Absolute values retain only the host from baseUrl and ignore any
>   specified path components.

as presently written, the path referenced in your call to `Endpoints.newuser()` is absolute, and therefore the path segments after the host in your base URL are dropped (as this is the documented behavior).

therefore, you should change your `Endpoints` interface to use relative paths instead, like so:

```
    public interface Endpoints {
        @POST("userregister/newuser")
        @FormUrlEncoded
        Call<Items> newuser(@Field("Data") String Data);
    }
```

Comment: if i use this then it will always goes in onFailure

Comment: @ParthAnjaria can you show the stack trace of the `Throwable` passed in the call to `onFailure()`?