# Retrofit 2 removes posrt after special character ":" from base Url

Tags: android, retrofit

I have an Api https://hello.example.com:344/new/search/result.
Implementing same using Retrofit 2:

This is how initialising retrofit:

```
  public static void initializeRetrofit() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://hello.example.com:344")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        service2 = retrofit.create(ContentService.class);
    }
```

This is the interface request:

```
 @POST("new/search/result")
    Call<JsonObject> getSearchList(@Body JsonObject request);
```

But when i hit api : it removes the port from it and hits

"https://hello.example.com/new/search/result"

What is going wrong?

Comment: try adding a trailing / after the baseurl like this `.baseUrl("https://hello.example.com:344/")`

Comment: tried with this also,same result

Comment: have you tried the url with postman or any other tools, seems like some fault with the url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit 2 removes characters after hostname from base url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352159/retrofit-2-removes-characters-after-hostname-from-base-url)

Comment: have u got solution @stackLearner?

Answer (score 1):

In your base url `"https://hello.example.com:344"` transform it to

`"https://hello.example.com:344/"`

Answer (score 0):

There is no / (slash) in your base url as well as in the interface function. So the request becomes like `"https://hello.example.com:344new/search/result "` which will give u an error. 
Add slash at the end of your base url like this `"https://hello.example.com:344/"`